# Make checkbox cause jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have and bootstrap datetimepicker in my form that is a required field to populate the rest of my page.

I can manage to cause validation when I use a submit button, but I have a checkbox that populates fields with the values from the datetimepicker.

I need the checkbox to cause the validation for the datetimepicker without the submit.

My code looks something like this:

```
//My datepicker
<div id="dtpDate" class="input-append" >
    <input required data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" style="width: 75%;" />
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>

//Checkbox to cause validation
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: setdate, click: setdates"/>
</div>


//My Script
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").validate();
});

$(function () {
    $('#dtpDate').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    })
});
```

How do I make the checkbox cause validation? (Without submit)

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to validate the text field upon click of the checkbox.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("form").validate({
        // your options & rules
    });

    $('#mycheck').click(function () {
        $('#myfield').valid();
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form>
    <input required="required" type="text" name="myfield" id="myfield" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" id="mycheck" />
    ...
</form>
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/rzjRM/**

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this is working and has been  tested in jsfiddle.

```
<form>
<div>
    <input required type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

javascript

```
//My Script
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.checkBox').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('form').valid();
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#dtpDate').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    });
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't cause jQuery validation?

Comment: Do you use a MVVM library like knockout?

Comment: Yes but the datetimepicker is not bound to it.

Comment: sorry it is formatted correctly now. I had formatted my snippet wrong and it wasn't readable. Did you say that this implementation doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

To validate your datetime field call **.valid()** after you have called validate()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialise validation
    $("form").validate();

    // validated the datetime field on checkbox click
    $('#your_checkbox_id').click(function()
      $('#your_datetime_field').valid();
    });
});
```